# Microsoft Graph - Allow User Access to Application / Service Principal

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, microsoft-graph-api

We are in the process of rolling out a major application to members of staff, it has been setup to use Azure AD/SSO and we currently have to manually set each user to have access to the application through Azure AD -> Applications -> Users. We have a small c# web application that we use to manage AD users are looking to use the new Microsoft Graph API to set users to allowed access when they are created but can't find the correct endpoint/api call to use.

We have tried the following but the documentation/errors returned are quite lacking.

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{id}/members

Which endpoint/api call should we use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking to try and set appRoleAssignments.  This is currently only exposed on the Microsoft Graph /beta version. The /beta documentation needs a little love and attention as you've discovered.  However this pretty much should work as it does in AAD Graph (so you could reference the AAD Graph API reference), but with the different root of https://graph.microsoft.com/beta.  This blog post also has some examples https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2014/12/12/announcing-the-new-version-of-graph-api-api-version1-5/.

Are there any specific challenges that you are facing?  What operations and errors are you seeing?

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hi Dan, the furthest ive got is either using https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/appRoleAssignments/{id} with a json body that looks correct from what i can see which returns a **Bad Request - Error in query syntax.** Or https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users//{user}/appRoleAssignments with a correct body as well that gives me a **Unsupported segment type**.  I'm going to have another fresh look today to see if i'm doing anything glaringly wrong, but i couldn't see anything yesterday.

Comment: Hi Dan. Any possible updates on this?  Using the https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/****.****@v********.co.uk/appRoleAssignments endpoint still gives me an "unsupported segment type" as if the 'approleassignments' is an incorrect segment?

Comment: @Dan Kershaw I'm trying to assign roles to a servicePrincipal after create an app. I get error when using the appRoleAssigments (beta). 
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/df9ce22d-3261-4170-aa9c-977d0945d43c/appRoleAssignments

Such as when:
  "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "Error while processing response.",

Comment: Apologies for the late response.  It looks like our /beta metadata is messed up and is not exposing appRoleAssignments on users or groups entity types.  @tatigo while it looks like appRoles are hooked up correctly on service principals, this also is not working properly. I'll respond back with more details on both of these.

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT Those are the steps I took prior appRoleAssignments:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583369/how-to-get-appkey-using-microsoft-graph-api

Comment: @RyanMnM Hi, sorry for reactivating an old thread, did you find a way to programatically assign users to your apps? I'm having the same exact errors when using graph api

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT I'm facing the same issues with graph API when trying to assign users to apps. are appRoleAssignments related operations still possible with the beta version

Comment: @Kira I answered on your other thread, which actually is the same as on this thread.  The answer hasn't changed since March last year unfortunately.