# How to get AppKey using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm creating new application using

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications
```

I can get the AppId back, but can't find a way to get the AppKey. I would like to access that app later using application credentials.

Update:
That what I send as password credential during the application creation:

```
  newAppObj.passwordCredentials = new List<AOBJ.AzurePasswordCredential>(){
            new AOBJ.AzurePasswordCredential()
            {
                customKeyIdentifier = "T1rEXhNmUUmVqimnBPkirw==",
                keyId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                value = "WgjbF8vG3GM1XRGpc43fvtiO7ScpTGwh0jd6CjIRd40dCX3kP8LMlCdcrrEPBRidI4CXW1OCnSQJQxOzX+oIUw==",
                startDate ="2016-06-01T13:59:30Z",// DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                endDate = "2017-06-02T13:59:30Z"//DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(2)
            }
        };
```

When I then generate authorization token using the secret key that I set before as value, I get this response back, when trying to use is to call MicrosoftGraph API:

```
    {
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_IdentityNotFound",
    "message": "The identity of the calling application could not be established.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "42d3f97d-5ccb-4680-a6c2-dceb160d19c7",
      "date": "2016-06-02T21:03:31"
    }
  }
}
```

When I create the secret key manually via Azure portal, the api call works fine.

Update 2:

So, turned out that the POST to create application didn't create the underlying **ServicePrincipal** object. I had to create it after the application was created.

```
 var servicePrincipal = O365OutlookClient.GetServicePrincipalForApp(InOnBoardingToken, createdAppObj.appId);
               if (servicePrincipal== null || servicePrincipal.appId==null)
               {
                   var servicePrincipalObj = new AOBJ.AzureServicePrincipal();
                   servicePrincipalObj.appId = createdAppObj.appId;
                   servicePrincipalObj.displayName = createdAppObj.displayName;
                   servicePrincipalObj.accountEnabled = true;
                   var servicePrincipalJson = O365OutlookClient.PostServicePrincipalSync(InOnBoardingToken, servicePrincipalObj);
               }
```

Comment: Are you now able to successfully call the Graph API? What parts of the Graph API are you calling and are you using client_credential or code flow here?

Comment: I create the app and the service principal grammatically but not able to assign the roles. So when I try to use the token I have the error "not enough roles". If I go to the Microsoft portal and click "save" in the created application (without any changes), it will do something behind the scenes and the token will work correctly.

Comment: to create the application I'm using the redirect to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={0}&resource={1}&redirect_uri={2}&state={3}";

Comment: We have an issue in MS Graph setting app role assignments.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36282758/microsoft-graph-allow-user-access-to-application-service-principal (which I think you are active on :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application password credentials need to be generated and set by you (either when you create the application, or later as a `PATCH` to the application). You can do this by generating a strong random value, creating a [passwordCredential](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/passwordcredential) and adding it to the `passwordCredentials` collection:

```js
{
  /* ... */
  "passwordCredentials": [
    {
      "customKeyIdentifier": "T1rEXhNmUUmVqimnBPkirw==",
      "endDate": "2016-06-02T13:59:30Z",
      "keyId": "e4003ae7-15be-487a-92d7-5d75aafdb4dc",
      "startDate": "2016-06-02T13:59:30Z",
      "value": "WgjbF8vG3GM1XRGpc43fvtiO7ScpTGwh0jd6CjIRd40dCX3kP8LMlCdcrrEPBRidI4CXW1OCnSQJQxOzX+oIUw=="
    }
  ]
  /* ... */
}
```

`customKeyIdentifier` is a base64-encoded byte array (can be whatever you want), `keyId` is a newly-generated Guid, and `startDate` and `endDate` are the dates in which the password credential are valid. The actual secret key is stored in `value`.

Comment: I was doing the same, the only thing i wasn't sending the customKeyIdentifier.

Comment: This didn't work. Please look at my updated question.