# How can I assign access to an application provisioned in Azure via the Graph API?

Tags: rest, powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We have several applications that rely on Azure AD to provision access. Having to manually assign access to each individual user is long-winded and I was looking to automate this process via the Graph API.

I'm using PowerShell to do so and I can successfully authenticate with the API and make calls to identify users etc.
What I'm struggling with is assigning access to an application programmatically.

According to the documentation this appears to only exist in the Beta version.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/approleassignment_update

However when I use the Graph Explorer this method is not shown by intellisense.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

If I try to call it anyway I get the error:

> Unsupported segment type

This suggests to me that this method does not exist and was simply not removed from the documentation.

There's an open issue on the GitHub for Graph [HERE](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/441).

There are some SO threads that had a reply from an MSFT and then no resolution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36282758/microsoft-graph-allow-user-access-to-application-service-principal)

[I found a C# sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console) which looks like it might do this but it obscures the details away behind libraries and I don't want to maintain a C# application.

I cannot find any information on whether this is even possible via the Graph API. Given that some of these posts are a year old I'd be surprised if Microsoft hadn't moved forward with this. All I can see are documents referring to the old Graph API which AFAIK is no longer used.

**Is is possible to assign access to an application provisioned in Azure using just REST and the Graph API?**

Comment: Hmmm, I think the changelog says that this was removed. Can't find anything else about why or what it will be replaced with however. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/changelog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, we can use the Azure Graph REST to achieve the same goal.

Here is the code for your reference:

```
public async void AssignRoleToUser()
{
    var client = GraphHelper.CreateGraphClient();

    ServicePrincipal servicePrincipal = (ServicePrincipal)client.ServicePrincipals.GetByObjectId("d90b4929-a2d5-43bc-8fc0-1e0adb640575").ExecuteAsync().Result;

    Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User user =(Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User)client.Users.GetByObjectId("b2d2cadd-21f5-4021-beb5-7b23ebd5364c").ExecuteAsync().Result;

    AppRoleAssignment appRoleAssignment = new AppRoleAssignment();

    // just use a known appRole id for this example
    appRoleAssignment.Id = servicePrincipal.AppRoles.FirstOrDefault().Id;

    // the service principal to add the group with the app role
    appRoleAssignment.ResourceId = Guid.Parse(servicePrincipal.ObjectId);

    appRoleAssignment.PrincipalType = "User";

    // the id of the user
    appRoleAssignment.PrincipalId = Guid.Parse("b2d2cadd-21f5-4021-beb5-7b23ebd5364c");

    user.AppRoleAssignments.Add(appRoleAssignment);
    await user.UpdateAsync();

}
```

In addition, if you doesn't sepcify the customization role, you must use the default id (zero GUID).

More detail about Azure AD Graph entity reference, you can refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#approleassignment-entity).

### Update

```
POST:https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}/directoryObjects/{userId}/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6

{     
    "odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.AppRoleAssignment",
    "id":"{roleId}",
    "principalId":"{userId}",
    "principalType":"User",
    "resourceId":"{servicePrincipalId}"
}
```

Comment: See original question: `I found a C# sample which looks like it might do this but it obscures the details away behind libraries and I don't want to maintain a C# application.` - If these libraries work they must be making a valid call to the API. I want to know what this call is so I can do the same independent of platform.

Comment: It is easy to capture the request using the Fiddler and I have updated it in the post.

Comment: Is that the old API? It's not the address referenced on the official Graph page. I'll see if this query works in the meantime.

Comment: This is the Azure AD Graph REST that published before the Microsoft Graph REST. And you can refer from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api). Difference between these two APIs you can refer this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/).

Comment: Both articles confirm what I thought that the old Azure API will be retired as soon as Graph API is feature complete. I think I'd rather wait until the new API is updated than have to rewrite the script later. I can't get this query to work, it says `401 unauthorized`. I assume the tokens that work against Graph are not the same as Azure.

Comment: The token for the Microsoft Graph doesn't work for the Azure AD Graph. To make it work you should replace the `resource` parameter with `https://graph.windows.net` when you acquiring the token.

Comment: While I'm unhappy about using the old API it does work (for now). I guess I'll keep an eye on development of Graph and hope we can assign roles soon. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the above post, as `await servicePrincipal.UpdateAsync();` should be `await user.UpdateAsync();`